# How can I delete ALL duplicated frames with ffmpeg and mpdecimate?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have CCTV footage exported from a motion activated camera system. When the camera is not active the exported file keeps time by overlaying a black rectangle on the most recent captured image, and then repeating that single frame until there is action again. (Kinda dumb.)

I want to get rid of all of the no-action frames. I have successfully used mpdecimate in the past to remove duplicate frames, but that always keeps the first frame in the duplicate sequence. In my case I want the first frame gone too.

Is there a straightforward solution to this?

Comment: That first frame isn't a duplicate, since due to the black rect, it is different than the previous frame. Is the black rect always drawn in a fixed position and size each time?

Comment: It is. It's automatically inserted as a timekeeping placeholder over the static "frame where movement last ended." If it would be helpful to see, I can upload a portion of the clip for you to see. Thank you for your help.